# Passing a front matter variable to a Liquid::Block parameter

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am trying to make a jekyll blog with github-pages.
In order to get some pictures from a folder, I used this gist: https://gist.github.com/jgatjens/8925165

Now, I want to make it a little bit more flexible so that it would get a front matter variable ( `page.folder` ) and would return the images from there.

My problem is that whenever I assign a folder variable to the front matter and then pass it to the block like this:

```
{% loop_directory directory:page.folder iterator:image filter:*.jpg sort:descending %}
  <div class="item">
  <a class="content" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ image }}" title="portfolio 2015">
    <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ image }}"/>
  </a>
  </div>
{% endloop_directory %}
```

In the directory attribute it passes page.folder instead of, for example "images/portfolio" which is defined on the front matter. I am rather new at ruby so I can't find something refered to that problem. Is it a bug or something that I need to write correctly to pass the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
{% loop_directory directory: {{page.folder}} iterator:image filter:*.jpg sort:descending %}
```

Comment: Yes I did, it doesn't return any variable. For example in the gist listing if I put print @attributes['directory'], iit returns page.folder while every other variable return their respected value. Is the front matter variable different than a literal one?

Answer (score 0):

I had figured it using the context object to get the front matter attributes,
but unfortunately github / github-pages do not accept plugins (_plugins folder), so a day was wasted for that.

I resolved to github's solution, to create a _data folder and use a text-based (yaml) format to list all my extra assets in an organized way.